# Gestures - control volume and brightness

Tags: android, gestures

I'm trying to build an app that uses gestures to control volume and brightness.
I have seen few videos that tell how to use gestures but not how to control volume and brightness. My main goal is when i swip on the left side of screen it control the volume, if i swip on the right side of the screen it control the brighness.
The only code that i found to use gesture is this:

```
    class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("TAG","onDown: ");

        // don't return false here or else none of the other 
        // gestures will work
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.i("TAG", "onSingleTapConfirmed: ");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.i("TAG", "onLongPress: ");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.i("TAG", "onDoubleTap: ");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, 
                            float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        Log.i("TAG", "onScroll: ");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                           float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onFling: ");
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Any idea from where i can start?

Answer (score 2):

This is my first answer in SO. I am posting some code here that is working for controlling volume. This code uses OnTouchListener for touch event, not  GestureDetector.

May be this is helpful..

```
//variable

    private RelativeLayout mRlTouch;
    private boolean intLeft, intRight;
    private int sWidth, sHeight;
    private long diffX, diffY;
    private Display display;
    private Point size;
    private float downX, downY;
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;


       //onCreate method


      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_volume_and_brightness_prac);

        ///THIS LAYOUT IMPLEMENT TOUCH EVENT
        mRlTouch = findViewById(R.id.rl_volume_touch);

        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    }



       ///THIS METHOD FOR GET SCREEN SIZE 
       /// USE FOR DETECT SCREEN SIDE

      private void getScreenSize() {
        display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        sWidth = size.x;
        sHeight = size.y;
    }




     /////onTouch method

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                //touch is start
                downX = event.getX();
                downY = event.getY();
                if (event.getX() < (sWidth / 2)) {

                    //here check touch is screen left or right side
                    intLeft = true;
                    intRight = false;

                } else if (event.getX() > (sWidth / 2)) {

                    //here check touch is screen left or right side
                    intLeft = false;
                    intRight = true;
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                //finger move to screen
                float x2 = event.getX();
                float y2 = event.getY();

                diffX = (long) (Math.ceil(event.getX() - downX));
                diffY = (long) (Math.ceil(event.getY() - downY));

                if (Math.abs(diffY) > Math.abs(diffX)) {
                    if (intLeft) {
                        //if left its for brightness

                        if (downY < y2) {
                            //down swipe brightness decrease
                        } else if (downY > y2) {
                            //up  swipe brightness increase
                        }

                    } else if (intRight) {

                        //if right its for audio
                        if (downY < y2) {

                            //down swipe volume decrease
                            mAudioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

                        } else if (downY > y2) {

                            //up  swipe volume increase
                            mAudioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: you did not mention brightness, and how does it detect screen size?